# Navigation with drawer and tabs like in Newstand

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to replicate the Google newstand app navigation system, where i can use the navigation drawer menu and tabs at the same time, like this:
[image]

I'm trying to achieve the exact same effect as newstand, single color for the action bar and tabs, and tabs not spanning for the whole lenght of the screen
I was able to decompile the app, and I've seen the source of another app that uses this (series guide) but they're quite complex and I can't find and figure out where and how it's implemented.

I have tried using the template that Android Studio has created for me for the navigation drawer and adding the tabs with no effect

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        /*
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);


        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Artist")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<PlaceholderFragment>(
                        this, "artist", PlaceholderFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("album")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<PlaceholderFragment>(
                        this, "album", PlaceholderFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
*/

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };
        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(new TabListener<PlaceholderFragment>(
                            this, "album", PlaceholderFragment.class)));
        }
    }
```

So far I've tried this using the android libraries, but i don't mind using external onex like actionbar sherlock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You're looking for Google's `SlidingTabLayout`](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/X8fg63wK6S8). And [SeriesGuide](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide) is open source, but uses [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

To use Google's `SlidingTabLayout`, you'll need to copy over two classes into your project. The classes you need are:

- [SlidingTabLayout](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)
- [SlidingTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html)

An example layout implementing the `SlidingTabLayout` would looks this like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <your_path_to.SlidingTabLayout
          android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewPager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After inflating the layout and initializing the `SlidingTabLayout` using `View.findViewById`, you call `SlidingTabLayout.setViewPager` to bind the `ViewPager` to the tabs.

[Check out Google's example for a full project](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, forgive the ignorance but how can i use the SlidingTabLayout in my app?
Usually I've dealt with jar files, I'd put them in the lib folder and that's it.
I'm using Android Studio

Comment: @DoubleP90 I made a more detailed edit. There is no `jar` to use, you copy the classes over into your project.

Comment: @adneal looks like SeriesGuide is now using SlidingTabLayout. thanks for the link.